# unable to merge android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

(Included in merge, but did not contribute any elements) activity:1.2.1 manifest, tracing:1.0.0 manifest, annotation-experimental:1.1.0 manifest, core-runtime:2.1.0 manifest, exoplayer-extractor:2.18.0 manifest, exoplayer-core:2.18.0 manifest, loader:1.0.0 manifest, lifecycle-runtime:2.3.1 manifest, exoplayer-hls:2.18.0 manifest, exoplayer-common:2.18.0 manifest, versionedparcelable:1.1.1 manifest, lifecycle-livedata-core:2.3.0 manifest, exoplayer-database:2.18.0 manifest, fragment:1.3.1 manifest, exoplayer:2.18.0 manifest, viewpager:1.0.0 manifest, savedstate:1.1.0 manifest, lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.0 manifest, exoplayer-dash:2.18.0 manifest, exoplayer-ui:2.18.0 manifest, exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.18.0 manifest, exoplayer-datasource:2.18.0 manifest, media:1.4.3 manifest, exoplayer-rtsp:2.18.0 manifest, lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0 manifest, window-java:1.0.0-beta04 manifest, lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.3.0 manifest, exoplayer-decoder:2.18.0 manifest, customview:1.0.0 manifest, android.app debug manifest, android.assets_audio_player_web manifest, android.connectivity_plus manifest, android.device_info_plus manifest, android.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle manifest, android.package_info_plus manifest, android.path_provider_android manifest, android.permission_handler_android manifest, android.shared_preferences_android manifest, android.syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer manifest, android.video_player_android manifest, android.vocsy_epub_viewer manifest, android.wakelock manifest  Merging Errors: Warning provider#com.crazecoder.openfile.FileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:9 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present android.app debug manifest, line 8

Answer (score 1):

If [this](https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file) is the SDK you're trying to use, did you see the instructions [here](https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file#android)?

> when Conflict with other plugins about FileProvider, add code below in your `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
>
> ```xml
> <manifest
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>           package="xxx.xxx.xxxxx">
>     <application>
>         ...
>         <provider
>                 android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
>                 android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
>                 android:exported="false"
>                 android:grantUriPermissions="true"
>                 tools:replace="android:authorities">
>             <meta-data
>                     android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
>                     android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
>                     tools:replace="android:resource" />
>         </provider>
>     </application>
> </manifest>
> ```